# How to track the unbound links using google analytics in shopify

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I have one Shopify store , here i am trying to track the outbound links from my site .

even i have found some code .

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var localserver = "trendsnaps.com";
   $("a").not("a[href^='http://"+localserver+"']").not("a[href^='https://"+localserver+"']").click(function(){
     $(this).attr("target", "blank");
     ga('send', 'event', 'links', 'click', $(this).attr('href'));
  });
   });
 </script>
```

But This code is tracking only "href" links . i wanted to store submit button out going links .

My submit Button code is

```
<input class="btn add-to-cart-btn" onclick="window.open('{{ product.metafields.google.custom_label_0 }}');" type="submit" value="More Info At {{ product.vendor }}"/>
```

"product.metafields.google.custom_label_0" is a external static link.

How can i track this links using that same way .

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly chain another function to the `onclick` handler

```
<input class="btn add-to-cart-btn" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'links', ...);  window.open('{{ product.metafields.google.custom_label_0 }}');"...>
```